# Why do I get an InvalidSignature error when uploading multiple images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-activestorage

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to save multiple images that come from the front end using a Rails API. I did the ActiveStorage migration but it still gives me the error.

Error:

```sh
ActiveSupport: :MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature (ActiveSupport: :MessageVerifier: :InvalidSignature):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:20:in ‘create'

Started POST "“/posts" for 172.19.0.1 at 2021-08-05 11:28:13 +0000
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"post"=>{"type_id"=>"1", "title"=>"test", "location"=>"calmo", "“category"=>"New Company", "“description"=>"", “images"=>["[object File],[object File],[object File],[
object File]"], "“start_date"=>"2010-03-02", "“end_date"=>"2011-03-02", "“start_time"=>"14:50", "end_time"=>"14:53"}}
User Load (1.0ms) [{"id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 8.0ms | Allocations: 3822)
```

[server side error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16hKz.png)

Post.rb

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many_attached :images
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```rb
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:type_id, :category, :title, :location, :description,
                               :start_date, :end_date, :start_time, :end_time, images: [])
end
```

index.js

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('post[type_id]', data.type);
  formData.append('post[title]', data.title);
  formData.append('post[location]', data.location);
  formData.append('post[category]', data.category);
  formData.append('post[description]', data.description);
  formData.append('post[images][]', data.images);
  formData.append('post[start_date]', data.startDate);
  formData.append('post[end_date]', data.endDate);
  formData.append('post[start_time]', data.startTime);
  formData.append('post[end_time]', data.endTime);

  post(formData, '/posts', function (response) {
    alert(response.data);
  });
};
```

Comment: please include the full error message in your question

Comment: Added the error

Comment: Welcome to SO. In future questions, please include error messages as text directly in your question rather than screenshots. Screenshots makes it more difficult for people to help you or future searchers who have similar problems.  I've edited your question with the relevant portion of your error.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the code for your controller's `create` method?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late but I had the same problem today and came across this post. Later I figured it out. I did a loop through the images.

Like you, I had like this (using your code above as an example):

```
formData.append('post[images][]', data.images);
```

And I kept getting the InvalidSignature error from Rails 7. Then I decided to do a loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.images.length; i++) {
      formData.append('post[images][]', data.images[i]);
 }
```

and the problem was solved for me.

Comment: I would like to also add that using the JavaScript for-in loop was causing the same error for me. I had to use the traditional for loop as @Joaquim described above.